# BOOST graph cc1plus: out of memory allocating

Tags: c++, memory, boost, graph, compiler-errors

I'm using BOOST for a graph mining problem, but when I compile it I got this error:

> cc1plus: out of memory allocating 1677721600 bytes after a total of
>   6270976 bytes

How can I solve it? and how can I improve this code to be faster and avoid memory problems?

Here is the code:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <queue> // std::queue
// for mmap:
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

//==========STRUCTURES==========
// vertex
struct VertexProperties {
    int id;
    int label;
    VertexProperties(unsigned i = 0, unsigned l = 0) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

// edge
struct EdgeProperties {
    unsigned id;
    unsigned label;
    EdgeProperties(unsigned i = 0, unsigned l = 0) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

// Graph
struct GraphProperties {
    unsigned id;
    unsigned label;
    GraphProperties(unsigned i = 0, unsigned l = 0) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

// adjency list
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties,
                              GraphProperties> Graph;

// descriptors

typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef std::pair<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor, bool> edge_t;
// iterators
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edge_iter;
typedef std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> edge_pair;
//=================callback used fro subgraph_iso=================================================================
struct my_callback {
    template <typename CorrespondenceMap1To2, typename CorrespondenceMap2To1>
    bool operator()(CorrespondenceMap1To2 f, CorrespondenceMap2To1 g) const {
        return false;
    }
};

//==========handle_error==========
void handle_error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(255);
}
//============READ ALL THE FILE AND RETURN A STRING===================
const char *readfromfile(const char *fname, size_t &length) {
    int fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        handle_error("open");

    // obtain file size
    struct stat sb;
    if (fstat(fd, &sb) == -1)
        handle_error("fstat");

    length = sb.st_size;

    const char *addr = static_cast<const char *>(mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0u));
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
        handle_error("mmap");

    // TODO close fd at some point in time, call munmap(...)
    return addr;
}

//==========SPLIT THE STRING BY NEWLINE (\n) ==========
vector<string> splitstringtolines(string const& str) {
    vector<string> split_vector;
    split(split_vector, str, is_any_of("\n"));

    return split_vector;
}

//============Get a string starting from pos============
string getpos(int const& pos, string const& yy) {
    size_t i = pos;
    string str;
    for (; yy[i] != ' ' && i < yy.length(); i++)
        str += yy[i];
    return str;
}
//==================read string vector and return graphs vector===================
std::vector<Graph> creategraphs(std::vector<string> const& fichlines) {
    std::vector<Graph> dataG;
    int compide = 0; // compteur de id edge
    for (string yy : fichlines) {
        switch (yy[0]) {
        case 't': {
            string str2 = getpos(4, yy);
            unsigned gid = atoi(str2.c_str());
            dataG.emplace_back(GraphProperties(gid, gid));
            compide = 0;
        } break;
        case 'v': {
            assert(!dataG.empty()); // assert will terminate the program  if its argument turns out to be false
            // cout<<yy<<endl;
            int vId, vLabel;
            string vvv = getpos(2, yy);
            vId = atoi(vvv.c_str());
            string vvvv = getpos((int)vvv.length() + 3, yy);
            // cout<<vvvv<<endl;
            vLabel = atoi(vvvv.c_str());
            boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties(vId, vLabel), dataG.back());
        }

        break;

        case 'e': { // cout<<yy<<endl;
            assert(!dataG.empty()); // assert will terminate the program  if its argument turns out to be false

            int fromId, toId, eLabel;
            string eee = getpos(2, yy);
            // cout<<eee<<endl;
            fromId = atoi(eee.c_str());
            string eee2 = getpos((int)eee.length() + 3, yy);
            // cout<<eee2<<endl;
            toId = atoi(eee2.c_str());
            int c = (int)eee.length() + (int)eee2.length() + 4;
            //    cout<<c<<endl;
            string eee3 = getpos(c, yy);
            //  cout<<eee3<<endl;
            eLabel = atoi(eee3.c_str());
            boost::add_edge(fromId, toId, EdgeProperties(compide, eLabel), dataG.back());
            compide++;
        } break;
        }
    }

    return dataG;
}
//============test if the graph connectivity========================================================
bool graphconnexe(Graph const& g) {
    return num_edges(g) >= num_vertices(g) - 1;
}
//====================print the graph information========================================================
void printgraph(Graph const& gr) {
    typedef std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> edge_pair;

    std::cout << " contains " << num_vertices(gr) << " vertices, and " << num_edges(gr) << " edges " << std::endl;
    if (graphconnexe(gr)) {

        // Vertex list
        if (num_vertices(gr) != 0) {
            std::cout << "  Vertex list: " << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vertices(gr); ++i) // size_t vertice number in the graph
            {
                std::cout << "   v[" << i << "]   ID: " << gr[i].id << ", Label: " << gr[i].label << std::endl;
            }
        }
        // Edge list
        if (num_edges(gr) != 0) {
            std::cout << "  Edge list: " << std::endl;
            edge_pair ep;
            for (ep = edges(gr); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first) // ep edge number
            {
                vertex_t from = source(*ep.first, gr);
                vertex_t to = target(*ep.first, gr);
                edge_t edg = edge(from, to, gr);
                std::cout << "   e(" << gr[from].id << "," << gr[to].id << ")   ID: " << gr[edg.first].id
                          << " ,  Label: " << gr[edg.first].label << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n" << std::endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Please check this graph connectivity." << endl;
    }
}

//=========================================================
/*bool gUe(Graph &g, edge_iter ep, Graph t) {

    vertex_t from = source(*ep, t);
    vertex_t to = target(*ep, t);

    Graph::edge_descriptor copied_edge = boost::add_edge(from, to, t[*ep], g).first;

    g[source(copied_edge, g)] = t[from];
    g[target(copied_edge, g)] = t[to];

    if (graphconnexe(g) && graphconnexe(t)) {
        return vf2_subgraph_iso(g, t, my_callback());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}*/
//=================test if the given vertice exist in the graph=========================
bool verticeexist(Graph const& g, int const& vId, int const& vlabel) {
    int cpt = 0;
    if (num_edges(g) != 0) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vertices(g); ++i) // size_t vertice number in the graph
        {
            if ((g[i].id == vId) && (g[i].label == vlabel)) {
                cpt++;
            }
        }
    }
    return cpt != 0;
}
//=============test if the given edge exist in the graph===========================
bool edgeexist(Graph const& g, int const& fromid, int const& toid, unsigned const& elabel) {
    int bn = 0;
    if (graphconnexe(g)) {
        if (num_edges(g) != 0) {
            edge_pair ep;
            for (ep = edges(g); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first) // ep edge number
            {
                vertex_t from = source(*ep.first, g);
                vertex_t to = target(*ep.first, g);
                edge_t edg = edge(from, to, g);

                if ((g[from].id == fromid) && (g[to].id == toid) && (g[edg.first].label == elabel)) {
                    bn++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (bn != 0);
}

// =============test if thoses vertices are neighbours============================
bool verticesareneighbours(Graph const& g, int const& a, int const& b) {
    int bn = 0;
    if (graphconnexe(g)) {

        if (num_edges(g) != 0) {
            edge_pair ep;
            for (ep = edges(g); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first) // ep edge number
            {
                vertex_t from = source(*ep.first, g);
                vertex_t to = target(*ep.first, g);

                if (((g[from].id == a) || (g[to].id == a)) && ((g[from].id == b) || (g[to].id == b))) {
                    bn++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (bn != 0);
}
//=============test if those edges are neighbours=============================
    template <typename Graph, typename E = typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor>
    bool edgesareneighbours(Graph const& g, E e1, E e2) {

        std::set<vertex_t> vertex_set {
            source(e1, g), target(e1, g),
            source(e2, g), target(e2, g),
        };

        return graphconnexe(g) && vertex_set.size() < 4;
    }
//===============if the graph is empty add the edge with vertices===========================
void emptygraphaddedge(Graph &g, int fromId, int toId, int eLabel) {
    if (num_edges(g) == 0) {
        boost::add_edge(fromId, toId, EdgeProperties(num_edges(g) + 1, eLabel), g);
    }
}

//==============================M A I N   P R O G R A M =======================================
int main() {
    clock_t start = std::clock();
    size_t length;

    std::vector<Graph> dataG = creategraphs(splitstringtolines(readfromfile("testgUe.txt", length)));

    typedef std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> edge_pair;

      if (!dataG.empty()) {

        cout<<"graphconnexe?"<<graphconnexe(dataG[0])<<endl;
        cout<<"verticeexist?"<<verticeexist(dataG[0],1,4);
        cout<<"verticeexist?"<<verticeexist(dataG[0],4,2);
        cout<<"verticesareneighbours?"<<verticesareneighbours(dataG[0],1,4)<<endl;
        cout<<"verticesareneighbours?"<<verticesareneighbours(dataG[0],4,2)<<endl;
        cout<<"edgeexist?"<<edgeexist(dataG[0],1,4,16)<<endl;
        cout<<"edgeexist?"<<edgeexist(dataG[0],1,4,12)<<endl;

        edge_pair ep = edges(dataG[0]);

        if (size(ep) >= 2) {
             Graph::edge_descriptor e1 = *ep.first++;
             Graph::edge_descriptor e2 = *ep.first++;                                                    
             cout << "edgesareneighbours?" << edgesareneighbours(dataG[0], e1, e2) << endl;

        }
    }

    // end and time
    cout << "FILE Contains " << dataG.size() << " graphs.\nTIME: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
         << "s" << endl; // fin du programme.
}
```

Comment: You have an out-of-memory error during compilation, so you shouldn't concern yourself with the runtime of the code after compiling yet. Chances are that the error is caused by generating insane amounts of intermediate code using templates, but it's hard to tell. My gut reaction is to throw another bar of RAM into your computer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I can't add any hardware to my pc, what can I do in the code to solve this ?

Comment: You could increase available virtual memory using swap. That said, you have a syntax error in lines 292, 295, 296, due to unbalanced brackets.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt code updated. How can I  increase available virtual memory using swap ? is it safe ?

Comment: That depends on your OS, just search the web for further info. BTW, which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm using UBUNTU 14.04LTS 32bits, g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2 compiler. Can I solve it by changing ubuntu partition size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an estimation of the lowerbound on amount of memory required live on Coliru:

- [16 megabytes:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8c10f1de0deb6d6)

  ```
  g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
  libbacktrace could not find executable to open
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
  ```
- [32 megabytes:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f9789e18ed54d94)

  ```
  /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
  ```
- [64 megabytes:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f47945dae281491)

  ```
  virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
  ```
- [128 megabytes:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f68d786b30eadc30)

  ```
  virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
  ```
- [256 megabytes:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83cfd78b30db60b6)

  ```
  virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
  ```
- [512 megabytes:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30460a98890b7621)

  ```
  graphconnexe?1
  verticeexist?0verticeexist?0verticesareneighbours?0
  verticesareneighbours?0
  edgeexist?0
  edgeexist?0
  edgesareneighbours?1
  FILE Contains 1 graphs.
  TIME: 0s
  ```

It looks like 512 megabytes should not be a problem. Fix your compiler setup

- computer with enough resources
- reasonably up-to-date compiler
- check the flags (try more and less optimization, debug information etc.)

On my system, gcc 4.9 with `-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -m32` works starting from 32 megabytes:

`$ bash -c '{ ulimit -v $((1024*32));  make -Bsn; }' /usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -m32 -isystem /home/sehe/custom/boost -march=native test.cpp -o test`

Comment: sorry I don't understand. in my case I got `cc1plus: out of memory allocating 419430400 bytes after a total of 5914624 bytes` what should I put in `-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -m32` and in `ulimit -v $((1024*32));`

Comment: You should google some of those things before you clamp down on "the experts". They may know a lot, but won't have time to chew and spoonfeed. Those are compiler flags. If you don't know how your build tool works, godspeed. Of course the [ulimit](https://www.google.nl/search?q=ulimit) is there to mimic a low-memory envirnoment. You shall not put it anywhere, since you're _already_ out of memory